# What's the link between a moderator candidate and me?

Tags: support, moderator-election, users

As many others, I've received an invitation to vote for candidates for moderator.

One of them has the following statement in their presentation:

> If you've seen my comments or recent posts

My reaction is *"Yes, I have already seen your nickname, but where?"*, and I would like to get an answer on this question, for every possible candidate:

- Did this candidate perform any action on a question I've asked?
- Did this candidate perform any action on a question I've answered, commented, flagged or other?
- Did this candidate flag any of my actions?

Using the answers on these questions, I could cast a better argumented vote. Does anybody know the queries I can launch on the site in order to get those answers?

Comment: You could write a query in [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com). There is no specific feature to find your interactions with another user, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: Flags are private, and shouldn't be revealed in any case. Proposing that flags be revealed for Mod candidates is a terrible idea. For "public" actions, that the action was performed on one posts shouldn't be something to take into consideration. Simply look at their public record, and if you like it, it doesn't really matter whose content they were interacting with.

Comment: @yivi: I was certainly not looking for revenge, but you are right that some people might, hence I agree with you, saying that flagging should stay private.

Comment: @Dominique I used the SEDE query linked in the duplicate on both SO and SU.  You probably remember me from [answering and commenting on this SU question](https://superuser.com/q/1708457/1210833)? And apologies - not sure how I missed voting on the question. I usually do upvote those I answer.  Rectified ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: indeed, I do.

Comment: Since you use WSL, you've probably seen quite a few of my answers ... :-)

Comment: Related: *[How to solve issues on closed Stack Overflow questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413202)*. The linked question has *"I just installed Windows Subsystem for Linux"* (WSL). And *[How to handle a software/tool release with a new feature that can answer many (non-duplicate) questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420488/)* (also WSL)

Comment: Personally, I think it only makes sense to inform your vote based on interactions that you actually already remember. If it doesn't come to mind, that's probably because it was unremarkable and thus gives you no real evidence for choosing nor rejecting that candidate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: "Every developer has a tab on StackOverflow" and I'm a developer :-) I mean: I interact with people via questions, answers and comments here on the site. Personal interactions only happen when I want to comment on somebody else's comment. This all is so impersonal (I'm just looking at a computer screen, not meeting anyone in real life here) that I almost don't remember the name of anybody, and I prefer not to have my moderator vote dependent on my poor memory :-)